# Slow streaming images in MVC 3 when more than one

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, stream

I have a problem with streaming small images from database using EF5 and MVC3

It works great when I stream 1 picture out, but when a page contains like 5 of those pictures its like glue and they take up to 5 seconds to load eventhough each are only like 5-200kb large.

[image]

I read some post and added this to web.config

```
<system.net> 
  <connectionManagement> 
    <add address="*" maxconnection="100" /> 
  </connectionManagement> 
</system.net>
```

It didnt have any effect on my issue.

And using this for streaming:

```
 public class ImageResult : ActionResult
    {
        public ImageResult(Stream imageStream, string contentType)
        {
            if (imageStream == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("imageStream");
            if (contentType == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("contentType");

            this.ImageStream = imageStream;
            this.ContentType = contentType;
        }

        public Stream ImageStream { get; private set; }
        public string ContentType { get; private set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

            HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            response.ContentType = this.ContentType;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            while (true)
            {
                int read = this.ImageStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (read == 0)
                    break;

                response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }

            response.End();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I removed the ImageResult and added return File...... speeds things up, but still not acceptable speeds..... 2 seconds for 18kb file.

Controller:

```
   [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
   public class ContentController : Controller
    {
    .....
       public ActionResult Thumbnail(int fileID, int width)
       {
           var thumbnail = _fileRep.GetThumbnail(fileID, width);

           return File(thumbnail.FileContent, thumbnail.ContentType);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the issue you are facing is caused by the fact that access to ASP.NET session state is exclusive per session. This means that if two concurrent requests are made for the same session (by using the same SessionID value), the first request gets exclusive access to the session information. The second request executes only after the first request is finished. You can read more about it here: [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) (*Concurrent Requests and Session State* section)

If your actions methods for the images doesn't require access to session, you can resolve your issue by decorating the controller with [SessionStateAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.sessionstateattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) attribute:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
```

This will allow the controller to handle the requests in *"parallel"* way.

In case when you need read access to session, you can try using the `SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly` value. This will not result in an exclusive lock but the request will still have to wait for a lock set by a read-write request.

Comment: Added that to controller and my class for ImageResult but its still slow as glue.

Comment: @LasseEdsvik Adding this on `ActionResult` class will have no effect, this attribute is suitable for controller only. Now what you are observing may be suggesting you have some other *synchronization point* which makes requests go *"sequential"*. For starters please add source code of your controller and the method for serving the images to the question.

Comment: @LasseEdsvik Well it looks like we will need to go to database level, so a look at `GetThumbnail` is also required. I will also ask what database you are using and how you are storing your images there (in general storing images in database isn't to effective, are you certain you can't create yourself a file store)? For a test you can use the same method but serve some static images from some folder. You will know if the issue is on the ASP.NET MVC level or EF level.

Comment: If I open the image in a new tab it loads in 25ms, so it must be some kind of MVC/config thing

Comment: @LasseEdsvik Not really, there can be locks/synchronization on lower levels (DB, EF etc.). Do the test by using FilePathResult (or pass the file opened directly from disk to File result) to get some reliable results - than you can be sure which layer is the issue. What your test confirmed so far is that there is some kind of lock when multiple requests go through. Of course keep [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)] for this test to avoid session lock.